# Excel 2013 converts text to dates in csv comma separated file

Tags: excel, date, csv, format

I am editing a csv comma separated file in Excel 2013.

When I enter 6/60 in a column, Excel turns it to jun-60 and I don't want that.

I've tried:

1. Choosing "Text" in "Cell format" options. I save the changes and close the program. When I open back the file I have: jun-60
2. Pasting only values. I save the changes and close the program. When I open back the file I have: jun-60
3. Entering '6/60. I save the changes and close the program. When I open back the file I have: jun-60
4. Entering "=""6/60""". I save the changes and close the program. When I open back the file I have: "=""6/60"""

I also had combined all the options. But it is not working.

Any ideas?

Please remember I am editing a csv comma separated file in Excel 2013 not a xlsx format.

Thanks!

Comment: If you edit your csv in an editor ="6/60" will be displayed in Excel as 6/60. If you then save the csv in Excel, Excel replaces it with 6/60, messing up the formatting when you open it the next time. What is your workflow, why do you have to edit the csv data in Excel. Is importing the csv data into an excel workbook an option for processing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

Use your own option 1. Do not re-open the file from the File menu, but import it as data (Data-tab, From Text). On the last page of the wizzard, choose 'Text' for the Column data format. That should work.